LWC - Community redirect to Home not working
I am modifying a lwc in a community in order to redirect to the Home page when you click on a button. The code is the following:
CommunitySiteLogo.html
<template>
    <img src={imgLogo} alt="" onclick={navigateToHomePage}>
</template>

CommunitySiteLogo.js
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';


export default class CommunitySiteLogo extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    imgLogo;

    connectedCallback() {
        const root = document.querySelector('html');
        const logoPath = getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--dxp-s-site-logo-path');
        this.imgLogo = logoPath;
    }

    navigateToHomePage(){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'comm__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pagename: 'Home'
            }
        })
    }
    
}

I get the following error when clicking:

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

Might be a bit random, but have you tried publishing the site and seeing how it works? I've had a lot of issues in the past with the preview in builder not working the same as the actual site.

For navigating to a named page in a community, you should use comm__namedPage instead of standard__namedPage.
Code:
navigateToHomePage() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'comm__namedPage',
                attributes: {
                        name: 'Home'
                },
        });
}


This is already the page type that is being used in the question.

Already tried. I have compared your code to mine and identified the difference, pagename != name. Thanks now its working!

Will this work for an Aura Community?

Yes, your code should work for navigating to a named page in an Aura Community. The comm__namedPage type is specifically designed for Experience Cloud (formerly known as Community Cloud) sites, including those built with Aura components.
